# Installing odd number of DDR memory modules

Tags: memory, installation

I have three DDR PC 3200 memory modules, two of which are 512 MB and one of which is 1 GB. My motherboard manual describes 1-, 2-, and 4-modules configurations; is it okay to install three?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not using dual channel memory configurations it should work.  Only way to know is to try it and see.

This is not a programming question, BTW and will be closed very shortly.